# Using Randint numbers in a caculation

Tags: python, random, typeerror

```
num1 = print(random.randint(0,9))
num2 = print(random.randint(0,9))
print(num1 ** num2)
```

When ever I try to run this in python I receive the error

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Anyone know the issue im having here and how i can go about fixing it?

Comment: `print()` returns `None`. Remove `print()` and leave only `random.randint`

Comment: `print` doesn't return anything. When you do `num1 = print(...)`, the result of `print` is assigned to `num1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are using the "print" - function which returns "None" as value when you try to assign the numbers to their variables.

In order to fix this issue, you simply have to remove the print-statements or put them in another place, so that your code looks like this:

```
num1 = random.randint(0,9)
num2 = random.randint(0,9)
print(num1 ** num2)
```

Take care

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 'print()' that you have putted in "`num1 = print(random.randint(0,9))`"
and "`num2 = print(random.randint(0,9))`", it should fix the issue.

Also you should change the last line to `print(str(num1 ** num2))` instead of `print(num1 ** num2)` :D

Comment: that second suggestion is less helpful; python automatically converts `print` arguments to strings as needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
num1 = random.randint(0, 9)
num2 = random.randint(0, 9)
print(num1 ** num2)
```

In your code, you are using `print` to get the value, but `print` statement does not return the value (as you wanted in your code) i.e. the return-type of `print` is `None`.